# How to convolve 2d signal with a 1D kernel without using loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image.  I want to convolve it.  I have different type of kernels for both x and y directions. In the function `con(u, v)` we can only specify one vector and we have to use loops. For `conv2(A, B)` we have to specify a composite kernel.  I want to approximate 2d convolution with a series of 1D convolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CONV2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) without problems.

For example, with one 1D filter being `firstFilter = [1 1 1]/3`, and the other 1D filter being `secondFilter = [1 0 1]'/2`, you can write the following:

```
out = conv2( conv2( yourImage, firstFilter, 'same'), secondFilter, 'same');
```